# Biztalk Flat File--Ignoring Headers and Footers

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I believe I have a general understanding on the steps on how to do this, but am struggling to get the schemas correct, either using the Flat File Schema Generator or tweaking the config afterwords.

I will give a sample of the data below, but in general, it starts with a multi-line header that can have variable text but always ends with the same exact line ("START-OF-DATA").  The next section consists of rows of delimited data (this is the only part of the file I need to bring into Biztalk).  Finally, there is a multi-line footer that always has the same start end end line ("END-OF-Data" and "END-OF-FILE").

Sample--my comments are in parens:

```
START-OF-FILE (this is always here)

(. . . variable number of lines that contain info I don't need . . .)

START-OF-DATA (this is always here)
(many lines of delimited data that I DO need)
END-OF-DATA (this is always here)

(. . . variable number of lines that contain info I don't need . . .)

END-OF-FILE (this is always here)
```

I have used the flat file generator to create three schema (header/detail/footer) with the intent to map only the detail.  I created a pipeline and assigned the three schemas to the disassembly stage.

I am looking for general tips on what may be wrong with my approach, or what I should be looking out for.  However the error I get when running this is:

> The trailer specification specified on the pipeline component
>   properties does not contain an interchange trailer.

I have googled this error and (as suggested) tried to change the Child order from Infix to Postfix, but this didn't help.

Comment: Did you consider keeping your flat file schema in one and add a port map to an internal data-only schema (i.e. ignore header and footer in the map)? It would simplify your pipeline and still leave you with the desired result.

Comment: Did you ever find out what was causing this? (I see you posted this three years ago). The accepted answer is a possibility, but I can't see why the Trailer Spec field would exist on the FF disassembler if you're not supposed to use it. Surely there is a 'normal' way to make this work?

Comment: Sorry, I don't remember the resolution.  I haven't touched Biztalk in years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this blog should help you:
http://maddcoder.wordpress.com/2012/06/14/using-biztalk-to-parse-a-flatfile-with-multi-line-header-and-trailers/